# can I check this RAM?

Tags: memory

I have a couple 2 gig sticks of RAM which are the right speed for a desktop i have but I checked on the crucial website and it said my board only supports 1 gig per slot and a total of 4 gigs. I was wondering if i could still do a memory check to make sure they work before I sell them on ebay. or could trying that ruin the chips or the motherboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can google the motherboard, or tell us and we can look it up. I'm not aware of any motherboard that can't be filled, if you have the right parts then you should be able to fill any motherboard up (power permitting).